# Call a function with parameters saved in a class object in PHP

Tags: php, function, oop, alias

imagine this scenario:

```
Class A extends B{
    public function hi(){
        echo $this->myVar->greeting("Hello", "World");
    }
}

Class B{
    public $myVar;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->myVar->greeting = $this->myFunction($x, $y);
    }

    public function myFunction($x, $y){
        return $x." ".$y;
    }
}

$myClass = new A();
$myClass->hi();
```

What I want to do is put in a class property ($myVar) a function which is in the same class.
And Call it from another class ("a child class").

Is this possible?

I know that from Class A I can do :

```
$this->myFunction("Hello", "World");
```

But I want to do the the complex version :-)

What I want is something like a alias inside $myVar which call the function.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If A extends B, like in your example, you can still use `$this->myFunction()` inside A...

Comment: Yes, I know it and I said :-)

Comment: I am confused by your question. properties are properties, functions are functions. `$this->greeting()` will call a function, `$this->greeting` will call a property. this is how php is built, and I think it won't change. Why not just name your property-method hybrid a method and be done with it? "put in a class property ($myVar) a function" means creating a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want `greeting` to be a function inside the class variable `$myVar`, you should try something like

```
Class B{
    public $myVar;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->myVar->greeting ='self::myFunction';
    }

    public static function myFunction($x, $y){
        return $x." ".$y;
    }
}
```

Note that I made myFunction into a static function. In PHP 5.4, when a string variable is invoked with argument, it will search for a function with that name.

**Edit:**

The empty value warning can be solved by declaring the property beforehand. Anyway, I had to resort to call_user_func for the whole thing to work.

```
Class A extends B{
    public function hi()
    {
        echo call_user_func($this->myVar->greeting,'Hello','World' );
    }
}

Class B{
    public $myVar;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->myVar=new StdClass();
        $this->myVar->greeting ='self::myFunction';
    }

    public static function myFunction($x, $y)
    {
        return $x." ".$y;
    }
}

$myClass = new A();
$myClass->hi();
```

Comment: I am afraid that it is not working: 'Creating default object from empty value'. You can see it here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/83c551513bbbeefe3e041416e3134a81f14b0fa4

Answer (score 1):

Look into [call_user_func()](http://php.net/call_user_func) or [call_user_func_array()](http://php.net/call_user_func_array)

```
call_user_func_array(array($myObject,'myMethod'), $argumentsArray);
```

Otherwise you can call it statically

ClassName::classMethod()